# CSS: How to use :not(a) if there is no a Tag?

Tags: css

I want to add different content via CSS. 
If there is a link within `<td></td>` it should show YaY and if there is no link it should show Boo.
But Boo is never displayed, I have tried different combination of :not()..

Its part of a software where I can't add HTML code, just can change CSS.

```css
.demo-td-1 > a::before {
  content: "YaY ";
}

.demo-td-1 > :not(a)::before {
  content: "Boo ";
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class="demo-td-1"><a href="#">foo</a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="demo-td-1">bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why can't you wrap the second row with a `span` element and then use that `span` as a selector for `Boo `?

Comment: I forgot to say that I can not add HTML code. Its part of a software and I only can change the CSS part..

Comment: I see... As far as I know you can't select an element based on its children, hope someone else might be able to help

Comment: You will need script to do that.